# El programa se detiene al ejecutarlo

Tags: c, punteros, busqueda

intento solucionar un problema que, dada dos tripletas ej: 3, 2, 3 y 3, 3, 2. Encontrar su representacion en matriz, donde la cantidad de 1's debe ser igual al numero de la tripleta, ejemplo:

```
 3 1 1 1       1 1        1   1
 2 1 1         2  1 1     2   1 1
 3 1 1 1       1  1       1 1
   3 3 2        1 2 1       1 2 1
```

En el ejemplo, las tripletas 1, 2, 1 y 1, 2, 1, como se muestra tienen mas de una representacion.
Dadas dos tripletas, debo ver si tiene mas de alguna representacion en la matriz, pero el programa no funciona, no se porque. Sospecho que el fallo proviene de la funcion eliminarSolucion y/o verificarSolucion, sin embargo no encuentro el error para solucionarlo. Lo demás creo que funciona bien. Gracias de antemano.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//se define una estructura que contiene la representacion de la matriz
struct matriz{
    int matriz[3][3];
};
//se renombra el struct matriz
typedef struct matriz matriz;

matriz *agregarSolucion(matriz *conjuntoSolucion, int *cantidadSoluciones, matriz solucion){
    //se define un nuevo conjunto solucion que sera retornado
    matriz *nuevoConjuntoSolucion = (matriz*)malloc(sizeof(matriz)*((*cantidadSoluciones)+1));
    //se copian los elementos del conjunto solucion al nuevoConjuntoSolucion
    for (int i = 0; i < *cantidadSoluciones; ++i){
        for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++){
                nuevoConjuntoSolucion[i].matriz[x][y] = conjuntoSolucion[i].matriz[x][y];
            }
        }
    }
    //se copia la nueva solucion al nuevoConjuntoSolucion
    for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++){
                nuevoConjuntoSolucion[*cantidadSoluciones].matriz[x][y] = solucion.matriz[x][y];
            }
    }
    //se aumenta la cantidad de soluciones
    *cantidadSoluciones = *cantidadSoluciones + 1;
    //se libera memoria del conjunto de soluciones que ya no se utilizará
    free(conjuntoSolucion);
    //se retorna el nuevo conjunto solucion, con la nueva solucion agregada
    return nuevoConjuntoSolucion;
}

matriz *eliminarSolucion(matriz *conjuntoSolucion, int *cantidadSoluciones, int ubicacion){
    //se define un nuevo conjunto solucion que sera retornado
    printf("hola\n");
    matriz *nuevoConjuntoSolucion = (matriz*)malloc(sizeof(matriz*)*((*cantidadSoluciones)-1));
    //se copian las soluciones existentes, excepto aquel que hay que eliminar
    for (int i = 0; i < *cantidadSoluciones; ++i){
        //se verifica que la solucion a copiar no sea en la ubicacion de la solucion erronea
        if(i != ubicacion){
            for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
                for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++){
                nuevoConjuntoSolucion[i].matriz[x][y] = conjuntoSolucion[i].matriz[x][y];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("hola2\n");
    //se actualiza la cantidad de soluciones
    *cantidadSoluciones = *cantidadSoluciones - 1;
    //se libera memoria del conjunto de soluciones que ya no se utilizará
    free(conjuntoSolucion);
    printf("hola3\n");
    //se retorna el nuevo conjunto solucion
    return nuevoConjuntoSolucion;
}

//funcion para construir una solucion, dada una combinacion de valores, ocupando la estructura matriz
matriz construirSolucion(int x1, int x2, int x3, int y1, int y2, int y3, int z1, int z2, int z3){
    //se define la matriz que almacenara en cada posicion una casilla negra (1) o blanca (0)
    matriz solucion;
    solucion.matriz[0][0] = x1;
    solucion.matriz[0][1] = x2;
    solucion.matriz[0][2] = x3;
    solucion.matriz[1][0] = y1;
    solucion.matriz[1][1] = y2;
    solucion.matriz[1][2] = y3;
    solucion.matriz[2][0] = z1;
    solucion.matriz[2][1] = z2;
    solucion.matriz[2][2] = z3;
    //se retorna la matriz con todas las casillas almacenadas
    return solucion;
}

//funcion que implementa las restricciones del problema
//las cantidad de casillas negras (1) por fila, debe ser igual al numero ingresado en esa tripleta
int verificarSolucion(matriz s,int *tripleta1,int *tripleta2){
    //se verifican las restricciones con las filas de la matriz
    if(s.matriz[0][0] + s.matriz[0][1] + s.matriz[0][2] == tripleta1[0]){
        if(s.matriz[1][0] + s.matriz[1][1] + s.matriz[1][2] == tripleta1[1]){
            if(s.matriz[2][0] + s.matriz[2][1] + s.matriz[2][2] == tripleta1[2]){
                //se verifican las restricciones con las columnas de la matriz
                    if(s.matriz[0][0] + s.matriz[1][0] + s.matriz[2][0] == tripleta2[0]){
                        if(s.matriz[0][1] + s.matriz[1][1] + s.matriz[2][1] == tripleta2[1]){
                            if(s.matriz[0][2] + s.matriz[1][2] + s.matriz[2][2] == tripleta2[2]){
                                return 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    //de no cumplirse las restricciones
    return 0;
}

void imprimirSolucion(matriz solucion, int numeroSolucion){
    //se entrega el numero de la solucion
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
            printf("%d ", solucion.matriz[i][j]);
        }printf("\n");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        free(solucion.matriz[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int crearSolucion(int *tripleta1, int *tripleta2){
    //se definen variables a utilizar dentro de la funcion
    int cantidadSoluciones = 0;
    int x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3;
    int cont = 0;
    //se define un conjunto solucion, que almacena todas las posibles soluciones del problema
    matriz *conjuntoSolucion = (matriz *)malloc(sizeof(matriz)*cantidadSoluciones);
    //ciclo iterativo para la busqueda en espacio de soluciones
    //con numeros siempre menores o igual a 1
    for(x1 = 0; x1 <= 1; x1++){
        for(x2 = 0; x2 <= 1; x2++){
            for(x3 = 0; x3 <= 1; x3++){
                for(y1 = 0; y1 <= 1; y1++){
                    for(y2 = 0; y2 <= 1; y2++){
                        for(y3 = 0; y3 <= 1; y3++){
                            for(z1 = 0; z1 <= 1; z1++){
                                for(z2 = 0; z2 <= 1; z2++){
                                    for(z3 = 0; z3 <= 1; z3++){
                                        //se construye una solucion tras una combinacion de valores
                                        matriz solucion = construirSolucion(x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3);
                                        conjuntoSolucion = agregarSolucion(conjuntoSolucion, &cantidadSoluciones, solucion);
                                        //imprimirSolucion(conjuntoSolucion[cont], cantidadSoluciones);
                                        cont = cont + 1;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("cantidadSoluciones: %d\n", cantidadSoluciones);
    for(int j = 0; j < cantidadSoluciones; j++){
        if(verificarSolucion(conjuntoSolucion[j], tripleta1, tripleta2) == 0){
            conjuntoSolucion = eliminarSolucion(conjuntoSolucion, &cantidadSoluciones, j);
        }
    }
    //se entrega el resultado al usuario
    //cantidad de soluciones = 0
    if(cantidadSoluciones == 0){
        printf("No tiene representacion alguna\n");
    }
    //cantidad de soluciones = 1
    else if(cantidadSoluciones == 1){
        printf("Tiene una representacion unica\n");
    }
    //cantidad de soluciones > 1
    else{
        printf("Tiene mas de una representacion\n");
    }
}

//Bloque principal
int main(){
    //se definen las tripletas representadas como arreglos
    int *tripleta1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
    int *tripleta2 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
    //se le pide al usuario ingresar los numeros de las tripletas
    for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
        printf("Ingrese el numero %d de la tripleta 1: ", x + 1);
        scanf("%d",&tripleta1[x]);
    }
    for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++){
        printf("Ingrese el numero %d de la tripleta 2: ", y + 1);
        scanf("%d",&tripleta2[y]);
    }
    //una vez definidas las tripletas, se llama a la funcion para resolver el problema
    crearSolucion(tripleta1, tripleta2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: He intentado seguir tu programa, pero es demasiado lioso. Una cosa a probar puede ser comentar los *free*, no es muy correcto pero salvo que te quedes sin memoria no te causará problemas y así puedes descartar que sea esto. Para un análisis más preciso, puedes usar una herramienta como Valgrind que analiza el uso de memoria de un programa.

Comment: Explica *Dadas dos tripletas, debo ver si tiene mas de alguna representacion en la matriz* Coloca un ejemplo de una tripleta con más de una representación. Explica que relación hay entre las dos tripletas que mencionas.

Comment: Ahí he colocado uno, gracias por la acotación.

Answer (score 0):

Lo correcto en problemas como esto es aplicar una solución recursiva con backtracking.

La función recursiva `llenar_matriz(fila, col)` coloca un "1" en la (fila, columna) indicada, y luego se llama recursivamente pasando la siguiente (fila, columna), hasta recorrer toda la matriz.

Una vez completada la matriz, se evalua. Si cumple el criterio, se retorna con éxito. Si falla el criterio, se vuelve a colocar en "0" la (fila, columna) y se vuelve a invocar `llenar_matriz` con las coordenadas de la siguiente (fila, columna), retornando el valor obtenido.

Es la esencia del backtracking: colocar el valor en una posición y ver si se puede completar el resto. Si no, deshacer el cambio y reintentar en la siguiente posición disponible.

```
int matriz[3][3];
int tripleta[] = {1, 2, 1};

/*
 * Llena una matriz 3x3 con 1 y 0 a partir de una tripleta de valores, 
 * de modo que la suma de la fila X sea igual a la suma de la columna X
 * y a la tripleta X.
 * 
 * Recibe: La (fila, columna) a partir de la cual comenzar a llenar.
 * 
 * Retorna: 1 si se pudo construir la matriz.
 */
int llenar_matriz(int fila, int col) {
    if (fila == 3) {
        //  No hay más celdas que llenar. Evaluar si la matriz cumple.
        return evaluar_matriz();
    }
    
    int nva_col = col + 1;
    int nva_fila = fila;
    if (nva_col == 3) {
        nva_col = 0;
        nva_fila++;
    }
    
    /* 
     * Procesa el resto de la fila, agregando "1" hasta completar
     * el valor dado por la tripleta.
     */
    int restantes = tripleta[fila] - sumar_fila(fila);
    while (restantes && col < 3) {
        int libres = 3 - col;
        if (libres < restantes) {
            //  No quedan celdas libres en esta fila para completar
            //  la cuenta pedida. Abandonar.
            return 0;
            }
        
        //  Hay espacio disponible para agregar la cantidad
        //  de 1 que faltan.
        
        matriz[fila][col] = 1; // Probar a colocar esta celda en 1.
        
        nva_col = col + 1;
        nva_fila = fila;
        if (nva_col == 3) {
            nva_col = 0;
            nva_fila++;
        }
        
        //  Revisar si con la celda en 1, el resto se puede llenar
        //  correctamente.
        if (llenar_matriz(nva_fila, nva_col))
            //  Exito.
            return 1;
        else {
            //  Fracaso. Deshacer la operación y tratar de colocar el
            //  1 en la siguiente celda libre.
            matriz[fila][col] = 0;
            col++;
            }
    }
    
    //  Si no hubo espacio para colocar los "1" en la fila actual,
    //  abandonar. En caso contrario, seguir probando.
    return restantes ? 0 : llenar_matriz(nva_fila, nva_col);        
}

int main() {    
    llenar_matriz(0, 0);
    imprimir();    
}
```

produce:

```
 1 0 0
 0 1 1
 0 1 0
```

Con `int tripleta[] = {1, 2, 3};` produce

```
 0 0 1
 0 1 1
 1 1 1
```

Nota:

Se ocupan las siguientes funciones, que no se incluyen por triviales:

- `sumar_columna(col)`. Suma el contenido de la columna.
- `sumar_fila(fila)`. Suma el contenido de la fila.
- `evaluar_matriz()`. Retorna 1 si la matriz cumple las condiciones.

El código completo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVZdbts4EH73KaZebGHHqn/qtyjeRYFN0YeiWLQvAbJBQVO0Q0AiVVJKmxY@TM@wR@jB0hlSlCnJTVvBlihqOPzmm29G4s/2nD88/CEVz@tMwIWtMqnnt3@NOlO53PbnjFR7mhtJVUHB8P7z9foGf6mbwfsyFxW7voENfFkl8DyB9SH15rYumHnPdV4Xik1oBsdT@DICPIIBrlumbmanDTirncz9tB9dwNqPZrOwmA63eLYJoMjg5ho3uPHeDu5sRFUb5WzT0SGGRfbtbr8AqgnD4wo3Dlpz82voyPJRhHdaZiCL0shCmklw@ZvcxKhbxC3ari0duJuqdpPxn8@zcTJkdJq21odRf81/atw8P9ApsCzuWF4jz97ZMJDf5FPuYNLVU3OdwpPNUYaB4X6ADcvLKJAwGOZi5RKxOBvBGbzOBeKq8e8DgfWnNSJEI7iHJTAomamkAawWMgpA6B4J0EbYBMgP3hc60/ChFoB5c/LI3NDl8QqsYCD3NcvRZ9cgkHNFfu7943afqznN0v@t4HIrzuE1gwn5TKBlKEZJDmkXrguhPjND/ihGEzmqtFHsHEO0EnFBWSNwjBm7QY1O8sAFrVi4ZHsPIddBpwn0a37nocFmA@s4RYsFwBsNt@weim9fLXCRZ8x6sjw4uPR6IkgtAIykQBrmo16a@9qL662tc3XH3vvyoPOMsh4/agqNLmkLvl3Tw3/0FSkseJnNBvsvzvwV2f7XaC4sA5EjelvpSBUJsL0Re6aQ/vFqjPTYiuRQuNSb4AFXOqlBxtCw1CYWSMMN5ikER7swVQkLUd24WodncW90fdEj/3grcwGT48qnT0ND6dQoKUFujXO9Rm9ok3YquHl6cQTRL9RGCZj5jKmgg2aZwMwSAy41qOgBF5EPJ3Oh0LoUmczYHF5siUgv9Ec7Q7fNdTT6CgUqbMm4xDxJW2olt8iMw@Jz5cjnGBrumXXWYl5XTtE7lmPs8@EOg76LNK5SWowi2bpSxVnNceR4cOwQK6sTzn4g71iYHXn/TOI/lPkpqT9C4VtxJ62vY2qjeRxGcqwC13ZEFuq/44JrYwSvGDawKip@J7BOIwqwkoB8Oh0I5fKTrPRJSUSMiRzxDIX60jDOrJ7DP8LeMi5c8nUpcFp@@19hs64MQ3VS7tvM5QM3Kwqeej72f0kxNZQ42XehnZJILxfuBX9KzXH/wV3fSVDYcuutbiXd1JQHmmvruo7H5vTCeIWvjqR1wdqSgkssVqSCcooxG6kTTOGeXhclaRfN5vEr9thK/sa36Dn8LG9pq6VD@BSVij4q2pC6HpYJLJvmdfyWSr2Dh4fv)